# Electron 22.0.3 On Linux Session Cookies Dilemma

Tags: linux, electron, session-cookies

I have created my first Electron app which is a dashboard that collects a list of URLs from a mongodb and scrolls through each URL using a predefined time delay between URLs.  I am using this to display information screens from different BMS systems (Building Management / Building Automation systems) which all reside on the same local network.  The BMS systems require user logins in order to view the screens.  I have created some code in my preload script which injects the necessary login credentials into the proper DOM elements and activates the submit method. (I know this is not 100% secure but to help that situation, I am running the dashboard in kiosk mode with DevTools disabled.  Further more, the systems I am connecting to do not contain any super sensitive data only temperature readings, etc.)   I create the main browser window once and call the loadURL method in a different function which loads the next URL in the list.  The problem I am having is that after rotating between all of the displays in system-A, when I load the URLs from system-B, the app has to login to that system (Totally expected behavior), however, when my logic finishes displaying the URLs from system-B and loops back to system-A, my app has to login to system A again even though I had already logged into system A  prior to displaying system-B screens and I never destroyed the original browser window.  Is there a way to maintain persistent session info to prevent this reoccurring login process when switching from system to system?  Ideally I would like to maintain the persistent session info until I quit the app.

I have read over the documentation for the session and cookies methods, but being new to JavaScript and Electron, I couldn't quite wrap my head around how to implement the classes.  Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What the different systems *should* do is to set a cookie on their own when logging in. That this happens could indicate that there is no automatic session detection on the side of the systems you're logging in to. Can you confirm this by logging in in your browser, then closing the tab and opening a new one, navigating to the same URL your Electron app would navigate to? If it prompts you for login, there's not much you could do about that.

Comment: Hi Alexander,  I just tried a test with Chrome, and it does allow me to switch between systems without the need to login again as long as I do not close out the browser, however, the same does not work for my Electron app.  I didn't know if Electron would automatically register the cookies or if that is something I would need to do with code.